# MongoDB with Sharding and ReplicaSets, I am getting confused

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding

I have a few questions, which I could not really answer myself.

What I understood so far:

Replication:
I can replicate data, so that on failover, my data can be accessed by another instance. Clear so far.

Sharding:
I can split my data into shards, that if my datasets become too large, it can add more data on other machines.

In mongodb I need 3 configservers, at least one masterserver (mongos, I need propably 3 to avoid beeing affected from a failover) and at least one dataserver(mongod, propably 3 to avoid failover) that contains the data.

My Questions:

- With what kind of hardware should I begin with on the dataservers? (Size of GB of the datadir, what would be good to start with?)
- Is it good to run the configservers on the data instances on extra instances?
- Where do I start the mongos on? I could do it on one of the 3 instances (config and or dataservers), but is it good?
- How do I know, that the dataserver needs a new instance early enough? (before it is full?)
- How many replicasets do I need? (or on what depends that?)
- I have on 3 completely different servers a zookeeper running, could I run my configservers on them as well, as far as the performance is fine or is that a no-go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With what kind of hardware should I begin with on the dataservers?

This is impossible to answer without knowing your working set. The amount of RAM MongoDB needs is the size of your working set.

> Is it good to run the configservers on the data instances on extra instances?

I would personally, for failover reasons, you don't want your config servers going down with some random replica shard.

> Where do I start the mongos on? I could do it on one of the 3 instances (config and or dataservers), but is it good?

The mongos is nothing more than a router for queries and it is a good idea normally to slap these onto your application servers so your application talks to a (or some) local mongos which then routes to your network. There is a small note that these can take some CPU/memory usage if you send a lot of aggregation queries through them.

> How do I know, that the dataserver needs a new instance early enough?

This depends on where your server is. I mean if it is on AWS you can setup alerts that automatically trigger the onlining and setup of a new shard when total available disk space in the cluster reaches a tipping point. However, this is all upto where your servers are and also who they are with and you will need to look into this more yourself.

> How many replicasets do I need?

One per shard. Basically each shard should be a replica set.

> I have on 3 completely different servers a zookeeper running, could I run my configservers on them as well, as far as the performance is fine or is that a no-go?

I have not used Zookeeper enough to be able to answer that.